# Draw ellipse or contorted circle circumscribing given data points in Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to draw an ellipse that surrounds the data points in a graph with a given centroid and data points in octave.

Below is a graphical representation of my data points.

[image]

Below find the type of graph I seek, The below circles are done in paint.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you interested in the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)? See `help convhull`.

Comment: Thanks A lot ,, Now I am able to plot the graph.

Comment: Cool, please answer your own question then sharing the solution.